# raw_input with limited time?

Tags: python, time, input

Is there a way to give the user a raw_input, but give a null response (`""`) if nothing is typed within x amount of time? I'd like to give the user 10 seconds to enter options when the script starts, but if time expires (or they press enter), simply continue the script. If you know AppleScript, I'd like `display dialog "Enter options" giving up after 10` in python

Comment: You _could_ collect the user input in a separate process, and then use the `terminate()` method on that process after a specific amount of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in unix-land, you can use python's signal library and use an [alarm](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html#signal.alarm).  Otherwise, I think `raw_input` is totally thread-blocking.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875008/how-to-implement-rediss-pubsub-timeout-feature#answer-10049595) for implementation help.